# Gaussian integral convergence

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

How do we show that the Gaussian integral$\displaystyle{\large{{\int_{{-\infty}}^{{\infty}}}{{e}}^{{-{{x}}^{{2}}}}{d}{x}}}$ converges?

I can figure out the convergence for $\displaystyle{\large{{\int_{{0}}^{{\infty}}}{{e}}^{{-{{x}}^{{2}}}}{d}{x}}}$ as follows:

We know that $e^{-x^2} \leq e^{-x}$ when $x \geq 1$ and then following this we get

$\displaystyle{\large{{\int_{{0}}^{{\infty}}}{{e}}^{{-{{x}}^{{2}}}}{d}{x}={\int_{{0}}^{{1}}}{{e}}^{{-{{x}}^{{2}}}}{d}{x}+{\int_{{1}}^{{\infty}}}{{e}}^{{-{{x}}^{{2}}}}{d}{x}}}$

and for $\displaystyle{\large{{\int_{{1}}^{{\infty}}}{{e}}^{{-{x}}}{d}{x}=\lim_{{{s}\to\infty}}{\int_{{1}}^{{s}}}{{e}}^{{-{x}}}{d}{x}=\lim_{{{s}\to\infty}}{\left(-{{e}}^{{-{x}}}{{\mid}_{{1}}^{{s}}}\right)}=\lim_{{{s}\to\infty}}{\left(-{{e}}^{{-{s}}}+{{e}}^{{-{1}}}\right)}=\frac{{1}}{{e}}}}$

so from the Comparison test, this shows that

$\displaystyle{\large{{\int_{{0}}^{{\infty}}}{{e}}^{{-{{x}}^{{2}}}}{d}{x}}}$ converges also, but Im confused with the one where the lower limit is $-\infty$.

Comment: It's the same idea. You just have to switch the sign in the exponent.

Comment: Not only it converges, but it is equal to $\sqrt{\pi}$. Have a look there: https://www.quora.com/Why-is-the-area-in-normal-distribution-equal-to-1

Comment: The substitution y = -x does not change the nature of the integral.

Answer (score 2):

Substituting $x \to -x$ yields:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{-x^2} \; \mathrm{d}x = \int_{\infty}^0 e^{-(-x)^2}(-1) \; \mathrm{d} x= \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^2} \; \mathrm{d}x
$$
Therefore:
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} \; \mathrm{d}x &= \int_{-\infty}^0 e^{-x^2} \; \mathrm{d}x + \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^2} \; \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^2} \; \mathrm{d}x + \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^2} \; \mathrm{d}x \\
&= 2\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^2} \; \mathrm{d}x \\
&< \infty
\end{align*}

Comment: Just noting quickly that this trick works for any even function over symmetric bounds.